# How to fix "EJS unable to access DOM causing Document is not Defined "

Tags: javascript, html, dom, geolocation, ejs

I am using Geolocation API inbuilt in HTML5 ,But the main problem is that,I want to store result from the geolocation Api in my db, Inorder to proceed over that ,I am Printing the result over console but nothing happened (In fact , I am getting document is not defined).I have also tried window too ,Still same response. Secondly ,when I am running the below code in ejs format on removing script tag, I am getting "document is not defined".

I have also choose another alternative method to resolve this issue , I made a empty form and through script tag I have inserted two input hidden tag and stores my result in it by using selecting tag by ID and simply change it's value to my desired result. But I am getting empty string in my backend file.

(Please give me answer in JS only )

I am new to NodeJs, I searched a lot before posting this question, didn't get the required answer. I really appreciate your precious time for solving this queries.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p> coordinate of your current location</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

   <% var x = document.getElementById("demo");%> 
   <%   if (navigator.geolocation) { %>
   <%     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){  %> 
   <%         x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;%> 
   <%         console.log(position);  %> 
   // Not able to print the position on the console but prints results on browser perfectly
   <%     }); %> 
   <%   } else  %> 
   <%         x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";%> 

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting desirable result in my browser but not able to print result on console.(USING SCRIPT TAG) otherwise I am getting "Document is not Defined" by using ejs format

Comment: document.getElementById won't work in ejs, simply use pure javascript, check this out [ejs docs](https://ejs.co/#docs), look at the client side support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any code that is between `<% %>` is executed *before* any elements on the page load.

When this line:

`<% var x = document.getElementById("demo");%>`

is processed, the `demo` element doesn't exist yet, which is why it returns undefined.

You can fix this by putting this code in a `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var x = document.getElementById('demo') //make sure this tag is below "demo"

if (navigator.geolocation) { 
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){   
          x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
          console.log(position); //client side JS will never print to your terminal.  It only prints to the browser.
        }); 
      } else   
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";

</script>
```

Or, what I would recommend is storing all your JS code on another page and linking at the bottom.

yourFile.js:

```
(function() {
    var x = document.findElementById('demo');
    ...
)}();
```

Then on your ejs template: //at the bottom of the page

```
<script src="yourFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, to use this method, you need to setup a `public` directory in the root of your application, then do this on your `app.js` page:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Lastly, I would strongly recommend learning jQuery alongside Node.js

It is extremely simple to learn if you already know JS because all it does is provide shortcuts for event listeners.

JS/jQuery comparisons:

instead of `document.getElementById('id')` you would simply write `$('#id')`

instead of `document.querySelector('demo').innerHTML` you would write `$('#demo').html();`

All you need to do is put this at the bottom of your code (but above your JS files):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

You can learn more about jQuery [here](https://api.jquery.com/).

### Edit

If you need to access this information on your server, there are several ways you can do this.  Before starting, make sure you have `body-parser` installed, or you won't be able to read the POST requests on your server.

body-parser setup:

`npm install body-parser`

### app.js:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

### yourFile.html:

```
<form action="/location" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="lat"  id="lat">
    <input type="hidden" name="long" id="long">
    <input type="hidden" name="test" id="test">
    <button id="submit_button"></button> //a button's default type = "submit"

    //you can also use a submit input like this
    <input type="submit" id="submit_button">
</form>
```

### yourFile.js:

```
(function() {

    //this sets the inputs when the page loads if navigator.geolocation isn't undefined
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        document.getElementById('lat').value = position.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById('long').value = position.coords.longitude;
      });
    } else {
      //this is to prevent the form from submitting if navigator was unsuccessful in getting location data
      //also this method uses jQuery because I don't know how to do this with JS

      $('#submit_button').on('click', function() {
        event.preventDefault(); //this replaces the 'event' (ie form submit) with whatever code is in this function

        //do something here
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
      });
    }

})();
```

### app.js:

This is where you handle the actual POST request.  When the form button is clicked, your server will receive a HTTP POST request with the route `/location`, since the form's `action="/location"` (in my version)

```
app.post('/location', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); 
    //this will print a JSON object with the values of all the inputs in the form
    res.render( ... handle the response here );
});
```

On a side note, if you or anyone is looking for a good class to start learning development, try [this](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-web-development-bootcamp/) Udemy course.  It costs around 12 USD but it is worth it if you are just starting out.

**Note:** I don't make anything by you buying that course, nor do I know the instructor.  I am recommending it because it was helpful to me.

**Note:** NEVER pay more than 15 USD for a course on Udemy!!!  If they are trying to charge you more then 15 USD do the following:

- signout of Udemy
- clear your browser cache and cookies
- change your IP address (you can use a VPN, or go to a friends house)
- create a new email/Udemy account and all the prices should drop for you

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying many things.I have one small doubt  ,how can I send this details or result to my main file (server side )?


I have also choose another alternative method to resolve this issue , I made a empty form and through script tag I have inserted two input hidden tag and stores my result in it by using selecting tag by ID and simply change it's value to my desired result. But I am getting empty string in my backend file.

here's my code link https://ideone.com/DBG2mp

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer.  Hope it helps