# use .getElementById() in EJS

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="specialTime" value="testament">
```

then in `ejs`, I want to access it like this:

```
 <% if (data.length) {
      var i = document.getElementById('specialTime')
    } %>
```

But the problem is, you cannot use `document.getElementById` in EJS. What would be the equivalent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "EJS unable to access DOM causing Document is not Defined "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714579/how-to-fix-ejs-unable-to-access-dom-causing-document-is-not-defined)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @charlietfl i need to get the value of id="specialTime", and use it within my `ejs`, which i later then use to access my database information in which i am passing as well.

Comment: You are confusing server side and client side code. You would get that value client side( in browser) long after ejs has run on server and page has been sent to browser. Your ejs does not exist in the browser, only the html it produces

Comment: @charlietfl interesting okay. So what would be the bets way around this?

Comment: You would either submit a form containing the `<input>` or use ajax to send data to server to get what you need for next step. You basically have two different applications.... back end (server) and front end (browser). The fact they both use the same language is somewhat irrelevant since the code they use runs in completely different environments and at different times